# innerHTML breakline cannot work in IE6

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- 
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = "aaa\naaa\nbbb";
document.body.appendChild(pre); 
//--> 
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but break line removed.

Why?

There are another good method?

Comment: yet another .innerHTML bug in IE. Issues with SELECT, TABLE,THEAD,TR too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = "aaa<br />aaa<br />bbb";
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer normalizes whitespace when assigning to .innerHTML. You might want to try .innerText instead.

see: http://stud3.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add <br/> instead of \n?